# Asp.net / Dot Net Nuke rewrite url

Tags: dotnetnuke

i'm using dot net nuke
and i need to rewrite my website urls
for example: from **products.aspx** to **products-computers/home.aspx**

I've tried modifying siteurls.config using this rule

`<LookFor>.*/products.aspx</LookFor> <SendTo>~/products-computers/home.aspx</SendTo>`
it doesn't work.
Please help!

Comment: Could you specify in more detail how this rule doesn't work. Does it fire at all? What HTTP response code do you get for products.aspx ?

Comment: Do you have both pages physically available or they are dotnetnuke pages?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the URLs of your website, you will need to use a tool like URLMaster from Ifinity to get the ultimate flexibility

What you are doing with the siteurls.config appears to be is define that if someone requests /products.aspx that instead of loading a page called products.aspx, they load a page with a path (defined in DNN) as /products-computers/home.aspx

That means that you need to have a parent page called Products-Computers and a child page under there called Home.

Answer (score 0):

I used to edit siteurls.config and it worked for me - you should be careful with syntax though. What I don't like re siteurls.config is that you're ending up on right page but with wrong address in address bar of the browser. So my preference is this solution that I investigated & tested personally and it was confirmed by stackoverflow community member as well:

[redirecting old site pages to single page on dnn portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706427/redirecting-old-site-pages-to-single-page-on-dnn-portal/22730414#22730414)